# Replace with .lengthCompare warning

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

IntelliJ keep suggesting to replace `.length == X` with `.lengthCompare(X) == 0`. Why is that better? Don't quite get it, since the suggested changes are more verbose.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is more **efficient**.

Since `length` is a `linear` operation on some collections like `List`, doing `x.length == 3` would need to compute the length first and then compare it with the value. On the other hand `.lengthCompare` would terminate computing the length once it finds that the comparison is wrong already.

Comment: You can add the documentation of [`lengthCompare`](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_5.html): Returns -1 if xs is shorter than ys, +1 if it is longer, and 0 is they have the same length. Works even if one if the sequences is infinite.

Comment: For my understanding `lengthCompare` is an abstraction to compare lenghts of different collection types which uses internal knowledge of the underlying collection to compute the compare result and is thus more efficient to use. As stated [here](https://pavelfatin.com/scala-collections-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: Scala 2.12 documentation: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/SeqLike.html#lengthCompare(len:Int):Int

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.13 we have `lengthIs` method which might be used to compare length of some collection just as `length` in this use case but with `lengthCompare` under the hood! So it is both efficient and readable. E.g.:

```scala
val list = List(1,2,3)
list.lengthIs > 2 // true
```

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/Seq.html#lengthIs:scala.collection.IterableOps.SizeCompareOps